# std::ifstream buffering affects subsequent runs?

Tags: c++, performance, buffer, fstream

I am working on an application that parses a 1GB file, and was taking around 22 seconds to complete the parse. I was trying to optimise the i/o as in production the application will need to parse a lot larger files, i.e. 40GB.
My first attempt of course was to attempt to optimise the std::ifstream buffer and found some interesting results.

1- My parsing method's read sizes are exclusively 4 and 80 bytes, I use read() not formatted input, so I tried buffer sizes from 128 bytes up to 1M. I was surprised to find that 128 bytes gives the best result. Even 64 bytes buffer size was almost identical to 128 in performance.
I don't get it how is 128 clearly better than say 4K, nor how is 64 byte, which is less than my single read operation perform so good compared to 4K or even 512 bytes.

2- More interesting is this, the 128 byte buffer parsed the file in around 14 seconds, the immediate subsequent run took 4s, next 1.5s then it settled around 0.7s!

Now if I run another file then retry the first one, it goes back to 14 and decreases again.
I checked with multiple test files, same results: subsequent runs on same input takes much less time.

How is this possible? and how is it even possible to parse a 1GB in 0.7s?
And it's not some weird bug, tests pass.

Can it be that the OS caches the entire file in memory?

My system is OSX 10.9.5 with 8GB RAM, xcode 5.1.1, Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang)

P.S. I didn't post code as it is too big, I will try to reproduce it with sample code.

P.S.S. Respect to he who deduces what the application does from these numbers :)

**Edit 1:**

As added info, the application performs around 250,000 read operation, a handful of memory allocation and some calculations that are mostly strait forward.

Comment: What does the "file cache" under `Activity Monitor` -> `Memory` say? unbuffered could be faster if the file is already in cache and does not need to be read from disk. Also, modern OS's read files buffered, even if you request byte by byte...

Comment: @taoufik unbuffered (or default) was not faster in my case, buffering clearly increased performance, but only with small buffer sizes. i.e. buffers of 512K and more decreased performance.
"file cache" says increased from 1G to 1.35G when I run.
Also default buffering did not result in the subsequent run performance increase, always takes same time.